# Compare username of running program to username logged into Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I've tried to implement a program which controls if the name of the user logged into the computer and the user who ran a program is the same, but I think I've done something wrong. The name of the usernamed logged works, but not the one to get the user who ran the program.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
using namespace std;
void Test() {
  WCHAR  UsernameSSR[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
  TCHAR  UsernameWindows[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
  DWORD  bufCharCountWindows = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
  DWORD  bufCharCountSSR = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
  GetUserName(UsernameWindows, &bufCharCountWindows); 
  GetUserNameW(UsernameSSR, &bufCharCountSSR);
  cout << UsernameWindows << " and " << UsernameSSR;
  return;
}
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: The GetUserNameA function returns 1 when run

Comment: I've found that in a docs so I tried to use that

Comment: [That means it worked....](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea)

Comment: Yeah.. but the function not working is the GetUserNameA not the GetUserName

Comment: ... which is the one I'm talking about, and which I linked to. Also you're having both function calls populate the same character array. I think you need to read the documentation page more carefully to understand what this function does.

Comment: I read it but I really can't get how it works, I tried with this code but I think I've messed up badly

Comment: You do realize that you're comparing the success/failure of the function calls and not the actual names returned, right?

Comment: All that these casts do is stop the compiler from telling you that you're doing it wrong.  They must go. The (LPSTR) cast is particularly evil, likely to produce Chinese or an AVE with default project settings.  Stop using TCHAR, it hasn't been useful for well over a decade, nobody still has an OS that requires it.  Start using wcout to display wide strings.

Comment: `GetUserName()` and `GetUserNameA()` are the *same function* when `UNICODE` is not defined and `TCHAR` maps to `char`. This code is only getting the username assigned to the calling process, it is not attempting to get the username logged into Windows. You need a different function for that, such as `WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTSUserName)`

Comment: @Shark44 Get rid of **all** of the casts.  Generate the compiler errors.  Read them carefully.  Reimplement your code so that you require **no** casts of those string variables.  Problem(s) will be practically solved.

Comment: I think the problem is that the semicolon(`;`) after `if`, which means `cout` will always be executed, and the `test()` function has fewer parentheses(`{`). What you might want to write is:
`if (GetUserName((TCHAR*)name, &size) != GetUserNameA((LPSTR)name, (LPDWORD)&size)){
    cout << GetUserNameA((LPSTR)name, (LPDWORD)&size);
    return true;
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetUserName()` is just a preprocessor macro that maps to either [`GetUserNameA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea) (ANSI) or [`GetUserNameW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamew) (Unicode), depending on your project setup.  Either way, `GetUserName(A|W)` returns the username currently associated with the calling thread, which in your example is also the username that is used to run the program.  No mixing of `GetUserNameA()` and `GetUserNameW()` together will get you the results you want, because they are going to return the same username just in different character encodings.

To get the username that is logged into Windows itself, you need a different function, such as [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) (A or W variant), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <wtsapi32.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>

void Test()
{
    WCHAR  UsernameSSR[UNLEN+1];
    DWORD  bufCharCountSSR = UNLEN+1;

    if (GetUserNameW(UsernameSSR, &bufCharCountSSR)) 
        std::wcout << L"UsernameSSR: " << UsernameSSR << std::endl;
    else
        std::wcout << L"Error getting UserNameSSR" << std::endl;

    // alternatively, use GetUserNameExW() instead...

    LPWSTR UsernameWindows;
    DWORD  bufByteCountWindows;

    if (WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSUserName, &UsernameWindows, &bufByteCountWindows))
    {
        LPWSTR Domain;
        DWORD bufByteCountDomain;

        std::wcout << L"UsernameWindows: ";

        if (WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSDomainName, &Domain, &bufByteCountDomain))
        {
            if (*Domain)
                std::wcout << Domain << L"\\";
            WTSFreeMemory(Domain);
        }

        std::wcout << UsernameWindows << std::endl;

        WTSFreeMemory(UsernameWindows);
    }
    else
        std::wcout << L"Error getting UserNameWindows" << std::endl;

    // alternatively, query WTSQuerySessionInformation() for WTSSessionInfo, which
    // returns both Domain and UserName in a single call, amongst other pieces of info...
}
```

That being said, comparing username strings is not the best way to determine whether your program is being run by the same user that is logged into Windows.

For instance, another way would be to obtain the [Security Identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-identifiers) ([SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid)) of the user who is running the program and then compare it to the SID of the user that is logged into Windows using [`EqualSid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-equalsid).

Getting the SID of the calling process is easy: you can use [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessid), [`OpenProcessToken(TOKEN_QUERY)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocesstoken), and [`GetTokenInformation(TokenUser)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation).

However, getting the SID of the logged in Windows session is a bit trickier.  You can either:

- get the Session ID of the logged in user, such as with [`ProcessIdToSessionId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-processidtosessionid) or [`QueryTokenInformation(TokenSessionId)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) for the *parent* process that spawned your program (to find the parent process ID, use [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot), [`Process32First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32first), and [`Process32Next()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32next)), and then pass that Session ID to [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken), and then query the SID from that token.  The gotcha is that `WTSQueryUserToken()` can only be called from a service that is running under the `LocalSystem` account, so you will have to write such a service and delegate to it via an IPC mechanism of you choosing.
- retrieve the domain\username of the user session as described further above, and then use [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) to query the [`Win32_UserAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-useraccount) table for that specific user and read its `Sid` property, then parse the SID into its binary form using [`ConvertStringSidToSid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sddl/nf-sddl-convertstringsidtosidw).

Comment: Just a thing, I get 2 errors while compiling, 2 references to external simbols (_WTSQuerySessionInformationW@20 and _WTSFreeMemory@4) which (it says) aren't solved.

Comment: Solved by linking to the library which contains the functions.

Answer (score -1):

You missed `,` after first parameter (`name`):
`GetUserNameA((LPSTR)name(LPDWORD) & size)`

Also, why did you use `GetUserName` and not `GetUserNameW`? In some cases `GetUserName` will be same as `GetUserNameA`, so if you try to get the difference write `GetUserNameW` directly.

Comment: The code can't compile without it so it is most likely a typo in transcribing the code here.

Comment: Mmh.. I think I messed up copying the code here, I'll edit it, it doesn't work anyway

Comment: So GetUserNameW will directly return a boolean?

Comment: `GetUserName` is a macro for either `GetUserNameA` or `GetUserNameW` depending on preprocessor.

Comment: Ok, but if I have to check if they're the same I can't just use GetUserNameW

Comment: If those functions are both `GetUserNameA` then it's just duplicated call. If they are different then you can call directly `GetUserNameW`. In any case, it's strange code.

Comment: I know.. I tried to do it just by reading the docs, the purpose was to check if the user who's logged on the os is the same as the one who ran the program (to check if he's using sandboxes or something like this), I don't know if you got it,

Comment: @Shark44 that may be what your *goal* is, but that is not what your code is actually doing. Not even close.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Any suggestion on how can I start to make it again?

Comment: @Shark44 I already told you in an earlier comment what you need to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried to edit the code, but if I compile I get my username as 1st output and 0x6efe10 as 2nd.. when I should get an username there too :/
P.S Check the code above to see what I have done

Comment: @Shark44 that is because you can't print a wide string using `std::cout`, it doesn't have an `operator<<` for `wchar_t` data, you are invoking the one for `void*` instead, which prints the memory address. Use `std::wcout` to print `wchar_t` data. But, it doesn't really matter in this case, because `GetUserName()` and `GetUserNameW()` are going to report the SAME USER, the one used for the calling process, not the one logged into Windows. What part of "*you need a different function for [getting the username logged into Windows]*" was unclear in my earlier comment? See the answer I just posted.